# how to provide print option in php

Tags: php

In my view page i have to provide print option that prints the page ..I am looking for some examples or link that can help me can anyone provide some link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use window.print() function in your Javascript code, When you clicking the button in the page